# How do it get all data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title kinda says, i don't really know how to join two tables, so i will get all the data i want from them.. I got two tables called: **leagues** and **league_point**

The databases in structured like this: 
**Leagues:**

```
teamguid        league         country
```

**league_point:**

```
teamguid         point
```

Okay, so far so good. I would like to join the tables whenever leagues.teamguid = league_point.teamguid i have done that, but i don't get the `point` column, I do not know what to get the `point` column. So therefore i ask you guys, since you are WAY better then me to SQL

Thanks in Advanced!

Best regards Emil

Comment: Do you have teams that have no points (no corresponding "point" records)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 1 way would be:

```
SELECT l.teamguid, l.league, l.country, lp.point from Leagues l 
INNER JOIN leagues_point lp on l.teamguide = lp.teamguid
```

Isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, something like this ?

```
Select league, country, point
From leagues l, league_point lp
Where l.teamguid = lp.teamguid
```